# The value of the field in the request is not passed

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

**What I do**: I pass discount_author in the request (in this case it is equal to 5).

**What I expect**: the value of discount_author will be added to the database and returned along with the 201 response when creating the bot.

**What is happening now**: the bot is being created, but it returns the default value of 0, and does not create a new value that I passed.

models.py

```
class Bot(models.Model):
    """Модель бота."""
    name = models.CharField(
        'Название',
        max_length=100
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Автор',
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        'Описание'
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category,
        through='CategoryBot',
        related_name='bots',
        verbose_name='Категории',
    )
    main_photo = models.ImageField(
        'Фото',
        upload_to='uploads/main/%Y/%m/%d/',
    )
    price = models.DecimalField(
        'Цена',
        max_digits=8,
        decimal_places=0
    )
    is_special_offer = models.BooleanField(
        'Спецпредложение',
        default=False
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Бот'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Боты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BotDiscount(models.Model):
    """Модель скидок от автора."""
    bot = models.OneToOneField(
        Bot,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='discounts_author',
        verbose_name='Бот',
    )
    discount = models.DecimalField(
        'Скидка',
        max_digits=3,
        decimal_places=0,
        default=0,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)],
        help_text='Введите скидку от автора в процентах (от 0 до 100).'
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Скидка на бота от автора'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Скидки на ботов от авторов'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.bot.name}'
```

serializers.py

```
class AbstractBotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Абстрактный класс, который определяет поведение сериализации и
    десериализации для данных, связанных с ботами.
    """
    # photo_examples = PhotoSerializer(many=True)
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    discount_author = serializers.SerializerMethodField(required=False)
    discount_category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    amount_discounts_sum = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    final_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    categories = CategoryNameSerializer(
        required=False,
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        many=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        fields = '__all__'



    def get_discount_author(self, obj):
        """
        Расчёт скидки от автора бота (округление значения в большую сторону)
        """
        try:
            discount = obj.discounts_author.discount
        except BotDiscount.DoesNotExist:
            discount = 0
        return math.ceil(discount)

    def get_discount_category(self, obj):
        """Расчёт скидки по категории бота"""
        try:
            category_id = self.context['request'].query_params.get(
                'categories')
            if category_id:
                banner_category = BannerCategory.objects.get(
                    category_id=category_id)
                discount = banner_category.discount
            else:
                discount = BannerCategory.objects.aggregate(Max('discount'))[
                    'discount__max']
        except BannerCategory.DoesNotExist:
            discount = 0
        return math.ceil(discount)

    def get_amount_discounts_sum(self, obj):
        """Суммирование скидки от автора и по категории."""
        discount_author = self.get_discount_author(obj)
        discount_category = self.get_discount_category(obj)
        return discount_author + discount_category

    def get_final_price(self, obj):
        """Вычисление итоговой цены бота с учётом всех скидок."""
        try:
            discount_author = obj.discounts_author.discount
        except BotDiscount.DoesNotExist:
            discount_author = 0
        discount_category = self.get_discount_category(obj)
        total_discount = discount_author + discount_category
        if total_discount >= 100:
            return 1
        else:
            return math.ceil(obj.price - (obj.price * total_discount / 100))


class BotSerializer(AbstractBotSerializer):
    """Сериализатор списка ботов"""
    main_photo = Base64ImageField()
    is_special_offer = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta(AbstractBotSerializer.Meta):
        model = Bot
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class BotViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """Вьюсет для бота.
    С возможностью пагинации, поиска по имени
    и описанию, фильтрации по категориям"""
    queryset = Bot.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BotSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitPageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, )
    search_fields = ('name', 'description')
    permission_classes = (IsAuthorOrReadOnly, IsAuthor,)
    filterset_fields = ('categories', )

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return BotReviewRatingSerializer
        return self.serializer_class

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Request example

```
{
    "name": "My Bot1234*-------------------------*",
    "description": "This is my bot",
    "main_photo": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/UrAWElx2NiVK....aVUE63ko0l5qHEzTkf8A/9k=",
    "price": 500,
    "discount_author": 5,
    "categories": [1, 2, 4]
}
```

Response to the request

```
{
    "id": 183,
    "author": "string1111",
    "discount_author": 0,
    "discount_category": 44,
    "amount_discounts_sum": 44,
    "final_price": 280,
    "categories": [
        "Грузы",
        "Такси",
        "Доставка"
    ],
    "main_photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/main/2023/11/06/16399c51-c2f0-4b2a-9e62-d831db2eb03d.jpg",
    "is_special_offer": false,
    "name": "My Bot1234*-------------------------*",
    "description": "This is my bot",
    "price": "500"
}
```

I tried to override the behavior of discount_author = *sterilizer.SerializerMethodField(required=False)*. I did *IntegerField*, but then an error occurs in *get_amount_discounts_sum*, where I use the *get_discount_author* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in django you can't save nested models you need to save it manually.

- first save the Bot into database.
- then create a BotDiscount that are related to the bot that we just made.

````py
class BotViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    # other code 

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # Extract discount_author from request data
        discount_author = self.request.data.get("discount_author", 0)

        # Save the Bot instance
        bot_instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

        # Create or update the related BotDiscount instance
        bot_discount, created = BotDiscount.objects.get_or_create(
            bot=bot_instance, defaults={"discount": discount_author}
        )

        if not created:
            bot_discount.discount = discount_author
            bot_discount.save()```
````

Comment: And how do I add this field to the serializer?
`I do this: discount_author = serializer.SerializerMethodField(required=False)`

**And its method:**
`def get_discount_author(self, obj):
    if hasattr(obj, 'discount_authors'):
        discount = obj.discount_authors.discount
        return discount
    returns None# or any other default value you want to return if the attribute is not found `

_So it doesn't take the value from the DB anyway_

Comment: you can make a serializer for BotDiscount model and then use it in the Bot serializer like `discount = BotSerializer(required=false)`

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to redefine the attribute and behavior of the abstract serializer class

`discount_author = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        discount_author = validated_data.pop('discount_author', 0)
        bot = super().create(validated_data)
        BotDiscount.objects.create(bot=bot, discount=discount_author)
        return bot
```